# Значения поля формы отображается не полностью в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

День добрый!

Работаю над веб телефонной книгой. При добавлении новой записи указываю номер телефона вида `+7 923 333 2211` (с пробелами). Далее на странице хочу его изменить, но он выводится не полностью, а только до первого пробела, т.е.:

```
<input type="text" name="number" maxlength="100"  value={{ edit_note.number }}>
```

выдаёт `<input type='text' value='+7'>` вместо ожидаемого `<input type='text' value='+7 902 922 2435'>`

Хотя, когда получаю данные через консоль, то всё в норме

```
>>> edit_note = Notebook.objects.get(id = 73)
>>> edit.number
u'+7 902 922 2435'
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы номер выводился полностью, а не дробился по пробелам. Спасибо.

Comment: {{ edit_note.number }} почему не в кавычках?

Comment: у меня нигде нет кавычек, и ошибки не выдаёт. А какие кавычки вы имеете в виду?

Comment: по всей видимости предлагается писать так:
value="{{ edit_note.number }}" вместо value={{ edit_note.number }}. Ведь maxlength вы пишете в кавычках, а value почему то без.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@mks](/users/5886/mks)](/users/5886/mks), именно. `value={{ edit_note.number }}` при рендеринге шаблона превращается в `value=+7 902 922 2435`, то есть `+7` браузер считает значением атрибута `value`, а `902`, `922` и `2435` - атрибутами без значений (ибо пробел - разделитель не заключенных в кавычки атрибутов).

Оберните `{{ edit_note.number }}` в кавычки, и будет вам счастье!